# Python filter dictionary unique values in a key and create another filtered dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

the question is trivial but I'm not able to do it.

I have this initial dictionary:

```
d = {'res': [1.1, 2.2, 1.2, 4.5, 1.5, 3.4], 'sp': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], 'obs': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

I would like to take each value of the `sp` key and transform it in the key of a new dictionary where, for each unique value I have another dictionary with the coherent other key values.

The final output should explain much better the problem:

```
new_dict = {1: {'res': [1.1, 2.2], 'obs': [1, 2]}, 2: {'res': [1.2], 'obs': [3]}, 3: {'res': [4.5], 'obs': [4]}, 4: {'res': [1.5, 3.4], 'obs': [5, 6]}}
```

so the keys of this dictionary are the unique values of the `sp` key of the original dictionary.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = {'res': [1.1, 2.2, 1.2, 4.5, 1.5, 3.4], 'sp': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4], 'obs': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

Given that input:

```
r = {}
for i, v in enumerate(d['sp']):
    r.setdefault(v, {'res':[],'obs':[]})
    r[v]['res'].append(d['res'][i])
    r[v]['obs'].append(d['obs'][i])
```

This results in:

```
>>> r
{1: {'res': [1.1, 2.2], 'obs': [1, 2]}, 2: {'res': [1.2], 'obs': [3]}, 3: {'res': [4.5], 'obs': [4]}, 4: {'res': [1.5, 3.4], 'obs': [5, 6]}}
```

To extend the first solution for any number of arguments is simple:

```
r = {}
keys = set(d) - set(['sp'])
for i, v in enumerate(d['sp']):
    if v not in r:
        r[v] = dict((k, []) for k in keys)

    for k in keys:
        r[v][k].append(d[k][i])
```

This results in the same result.

Using `if v not in r:` over `setdefault` saves creating a lot of dictionary and list objects but when the structure is simple that is not much of a cost.

Comment: thanks for the super quick answer. I get this error with your code: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: 'res'

Comment: That error doesn't occur in this code. What code did you actually run?

Answer (score 0):

For the more general case (with arbitrary number of keys)

```
new_dict = {}

for current_value in set(d['sp']):
    new_dict[current_value] = {}
    indices = [current_value == val for val in d['sp']]

    for key, values in d.items():
        if key != 'sp':
            filtered_values = []
            for value, index in zip(values, indices):
                if index:
                    filtered_values.append(value)

            new_dict[current_value][key] = filtered_values
```